# PHP function to convert unicode to special characters?

Tags: php, unicode

Is there a php function to handle the encodings below?

```
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0080", "&Agrave;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0081", "&Aacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0082", "&Acirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0083", "&Atilde;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0084", "&Auml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0085", "&Aring;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0086", "&AElig;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a0", "&agrave;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a1", "&aacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a2", "&acirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a3", "&atilde;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a4", "&auml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a5", "&aring;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a6", "&aelig;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0087", "&Ccedil;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a7", "&ccedil;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0090", "&ETH;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00b0", "&eth;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0088", "&Egrave;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0089", "&Eacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u008a", "&Ecirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u008b", "&Euml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a8", "&egrave;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00a9", "&eacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00aa", "&ecirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00ab", "&euml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u008c", "&Igrave;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u008d", "&Iacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u008e", "&Icirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u008f", "&Iuml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00ac", "&igrave;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00ad", "&iacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00ae", "&icirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00af", "&iuml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0091", "&Ntilde;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00b1", "&ntilde;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0092", "&Ograve;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0093", "&Oacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0094", "&Ocirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0095", "&Otilde;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0096", "&Ouml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0098", "&Oslash;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c5\u0092", "&OElig;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00b2", "&ograve;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00b3", "&oacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00b4", "&ocirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00b5", "&otilde;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00b6", "&ouml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00b8", "&oslash;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c5\u0093", "&oelig;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u0099", "&Ugrave;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u009a", "&Uacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u009b", "&Ucirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u009c", "&Uuml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00b9", "&ugrave;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00ba", "&uacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00bb", "&ucirc;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00bc", "&uuml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u009d", "&Yacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c5\u00b8", "&Yuml;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00bd", "&yacute;")
  .replaceAll("\u00c3\u00bf", "&yuml;");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) with the "to" encoding as `'HTML-ENTITIES'`, and (if necessary) the "from" encoding set to `'UTF-8'` or whichever Unicode encoding you're using.

Comment: In php6, there won't be need for MultiByte (mb) anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I found this to be interesting, where the previous answer was not working :

```
function jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($struct) {
   return preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))", json_encode($struct));
}
```

I found it here : http://www.avoid.org/replace-u-characters-in-json-string/

Answer (score 2):

Use [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), it's blazing fast.

Comment: Doesn't work, since html entities are multiple characters, and `strtr()` only does 1:1 character mappings.

Comment: That's incorrect, it can operate on the key->value pairs of an array (replacing each occurance of 'key' by 'value'), where you can replace multi-character strings.