# Doctrine2 special characters wasters

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, special-characters

I use doctrine 2... So some records (entities) in DB contains special characters and when Im reviewing text in phpmyadmin it shows correct text

> 35,000 years BP: Oase 1 (mandible) and Oase 2 (cranium) were both discovered in the Peştera cu Oase, Romania. The mandible was found first, in 2002, by speleologists Milota, Bîlgăr and Sarcină....

but in my entity on debug pause and in page on frontend I see wasters

> 35,000 years BP: Oase 1 (mandible) and Oase 2 (cranium) were both discovered in the Pe?tera cu Oase, Romania. The mandible was found first, in 2002, by speleologists Milota, B�lg?r and Sarcin?...

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you specified the encoding on the frontend? e.g. `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: @dchesterton meta charset already defined, and how it explains that in xdebug there are incorrect chars?

Comment: OP has identified their own question as a duplicate of [PHP function to convert unicode to special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577871/php-function-to-convert-unicode-to-special-characters)

Comment: @sjagr yes u are right!)_

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer that satisfied me...
[PHP function to convert unicode to special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577871/php-function-to-convert-unicode-to-special-characters)

```
<?php echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'); ?>
```